# Save Arabic list of string in database

Tags: list, sql-server-2012, c#-2.0

I have text file. I am reading the text document and split it into an array. I try to remove white space. So I move the elements of array into list of string.
Here part of code

```
 List<string> words =new List<string>();
           string allcomments = File.ReadAllText("D:\\all comment.txt");//read text flile
           string[] tc = allcomments.Split(' '); //split contains of text flie into tokens
           foreach (string t in tc) 
           {
               string token = t;
               token = token.Trim();//to remove white spaces
               words.Add(token);
           }
                            //save list of words in the database
                      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-JRS3DQ4; DataBase=My_Project; Integrated Security=true");
              connection.Open();

              SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tokens_all_comments (tokens) VALUES (@tokens)", connection);
              command.Parameters.Add("@tokens", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250); //size and type must match your DB

              foreach(var w in words)
              {
                  command.Parameters["@tokens"].Value = _words[w];
                  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
              connection.Close();
```

When I try to run the code, following error is appeared

> Error3    The name '_words' does not exist in the current context

How can I fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here:

```
foreach(var w in words)
{
  command.Parameters["@tokens"].Value = _words[w];
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You are trying to use `_words` which isn't declared anywhere. It's a typo, I believe you wanted to use `words` (without the underscore).

---

You are already cycling the words in the `foreach`, so you don't have to access `words` as an array, but directly the variable `w` declared in the foreach. Also, currently you will only leave the last word as the sql parameter, since you aren't concatenating their value, it's always being assigned.

You can concatenate all words without the `foreach` using `String.Join()`:

```
command.Parameters["@tokens"].Value = String.Join("", words.ToArray());
```

You can also omit all the split and foreach and directly remove all white spaces with a simple `replace()`:

```
command.Parameters["@tokens"].Value = allcomments.Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: @AfraArif glad to help :)